# (C-)Kermit suddenly stopped working on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, serial-port, rs232

I've been using (C-)Kermit for decades to communicate with my various HP48GXs. My current setup as regards the environment in which I run (C-)Kermit is primarily on a Linux Mint Vera 21.1 Cinnamon 64-bit VMware VM on the latest version of Windows 10 x64 using "C-Kermit 9.0.305 OPEN SOURCE: Alpha.07, 24 Jan 2022, for Linux+SSL (64-bit)" installed via the default system repos.

Over three months ago, I installed an update to VMware 17.x ( where x < 5 ) and suddenly I could no longer connect or transfer data and/or files to or from my HP48GXs within the VM. I updated VMware to version 17.5 which didn't solve the problem. Currently, I'm using the latest version of VMware but it seems to make no difference. Just recently, I installed C-Kermit 10.0 for Windows Beta 5 and that doesn't work either. In each case, when trying to transfer a file via Kermit, it seems as if Kermit can transmit data but not receive it. That is, Kermit transmits a packet but never receives an ACK and eventually errors out in the retransmission no-ACK sequence.

I've run a serial port monitor in Windows, and, when Kermit tries to transmit anything I see a large number of IRP_MJ_READ system calls with STATUS_TIMEOUT. If, however, I use eg. SecureCRT I **can** transmit data to my HP48GXs with no problems using XMODEM.

In the Linux VM case, the USB serial device node seems to be correctly created as /dev/ttyUSB*. Also, dmesg and udevadm report that the device is correctly set up and functioning. In the native Windows 10 x64 case the device manager reports that the USB-to-serial adapter is working properly and has been allocated COM3.

I have tried different HP48GXs with the same results. Also, I've tried a Keyspan USA-19HS USB-to-serial adapter as well as an FTDI Chip UT232R-500 USB-to-serial-adapter with no change. Note that in the case of the Keyspan adapter the green LED changes from blinking to solid when the COM port in Windows or the USB tty device node in Linux is configured and its speed is set, which reinforces the notion that there's no hardware problem on the USB-to-serial side at least.

Note that I **can** get C-Kermit to work with my HP48GXs on my Intel NUC8i7BEH running an older version of Linux Mint ( I apologize if I don't remember the exact version of the OS ). This makes me think that the problem is the Windows install or the hardware on which I'm running Kermit, which is a Dell Alienware 17 R5.

At this point I don't know what to do.